# how to port cocos2d-js to android and iphone(ipad) in cocos code ide

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-js

I am new cocos2d developer.

I am studying cocos2d-js using cocos code Ide in windows.

My programming language for cocos2d-js is javascript.

Cocos code Ide provides good editing and testing enviroment to develop cocos2d-js.

but I can't generate from the project in cocos code Ide to the release products for all platform.

In project folder, there are some directories that contain apk and ipa and other format products, but they are only debugging product.

I want to know how to make clean product for all platform from cocos2d-js project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_build_a_simple_game_with_Cocos_Code_IDE

or right click on project -> export -> export to apk
something like so

Comment: Thank you for your response kindly.\n
i cant find any project->export->export to apk And when i do package to apk,it returns error 1 in the last step.

Comment: check out the NDK version compatibility it was give me same errore i fixed it by changing NDK version 

personal opinion : i dont recommend using cocos IDE it is a lot of bugs and errors instead you may want to use Visual Studio or Xcode for mac 

to compile or package it to android use command line it is very simple
cocos compile -p android

Comment: thank you for kindly response. by the way i can't find the way to use cocos2d-js in visual studio. does visual studio support java script project coding and debugging? because cocos2d-js is java script language based framework. Thank you

Comment: yes it support javascript but you have to compile it using command line on windows or bash on mac for example after coding your game change directory o the project

for example
 cd d:/cocosGame
cocos run -p web

and it will run the game in the browser after second

Comment: if you found my comments helpful please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: thank you. you are the good helper. i want to mark your answer as correct. btw, how to mark? plz send the way. i will mark you.

Comment: under my anser you will fiend mark , click on it to make it green :)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/104yuxlhfpg8vbs/Untitled.jpg?dl=0